# How do submit a pull request for a feature branch that has my changes

Tags: git, github, merge, git-branch, rebase

Here is my scenario.

I have a branch where I perform code iterations.

I then have a branch off of that when I want to freeze the code base.

If a bug is found in the frozen code base, then I have to create a feature branch off the frozen code base and merge back into the frozen code base. So the scenario looks like this:

- branch1

  - branch 2 (frozen)

I have an identified bug:

- branch 1

  - branch 2 (frozen)
  - branch 3 (feature branch to fix code bug in branch 2)

I am always iterating in branch1 so this branch should not come into play.

The problem I am having is I am seeing commits outside of mine in my github pull request.

- Someone pushes a bugfix to branch2 (remote).
- The same change is not in branch1.
- I fetch and rebase branch2 (locally).
- I merge the changes into branch3.
- I push my new branch3 upstream to github (remote).

I now not only see my change, but I also see the last commit in branch2 in my pull request.

Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can get around the issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you merge the changes in, try using the `--no-ff` option, i.e.

`git commit --no-ff -m"msg"`  to preserve the commit history and place the changes at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the issue is: <<

- I fetch and rebase branch2 (locally).
- I merge the changes into branch3. >>

For such a case, I prefer to perform a rebase to branch2 onto branch3:

```
git checkout branch3
git rebase branch2
```

That will re-apply your changes after having reset branch3 to branch2. That way, the PR stay clean and in case of conflicts, you will have to solve your own changes, not those coming from someone else.

Note you will have to force the push of branch3 since its history has changed but that's not an issue for a temporary feature branch.